# could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Please help me out of this problem. I am new to postgresql and i did i big mistake. I am using postgresql 10 and logical replication. I had no knowledge but my server is out of memory today so i find out that pg_wal had soo many wal backups. So I try to figure out a way and perform this command

```
find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

and after that i am getting error

could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map"

and i am unable to connect my database. It showing  could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "172.104.169.169" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Please give me some solution. 
Thanks in advance.
System - Ubuntu
Postgresql 10

Comment: @craig-ringer please help me out.

Comment: please post the result of `echo $ARCHIVEDIR` in shell - I'm curious too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be interesting to know where the variable `ARCHIVEDIR` pointed.

Is the file `global/pg_filenode.map` present in your PostgreSQL data directory?

Odds are that you not only deleted that file, but other vital files as well. To begin with, the files in `pg_wal` *are* vital files. They are *not* backups, and you should never delete them yourself.

Very likely your database is toast at this point, so you should restore from a backup. Since you have replication set up, you may also be able to get the data from the replica.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i had my last backup on amazon s3. So you are saying that i have to restore last backup. But right  now i am facing that i am  unable to run psql. It showing not accepting connction on port 5432

Comment: Stop the database process, remove all remaining files. If it is a logocal backup (`pg_dump`), run `initdb` to create a new PostgreSQL cluster and restore. If it is a physical backup, restore it and recover to a point before the problem happened.

Comment: i quick question if you dont mind ...is that my data is recoverable, because on my /var/lib/postgresql/10/main , their is no global folder

Comment: Is that your $PGDATA? If yes, then it should definitely have a `global` subdirectory. I think that your data are *not* recoverable, that's why I recommended restoring a backup.